# React Application Update Data from DynamoDB Change

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am building a React application with GraphQL using AWS AppSync with DynamoDB. My use case is that I have a table of data that is being pulled from a DynamoDB table and displayed to the user using GraphQL. I have a few fields that are being updated by step functions running on AWS. I need those fields to be automatically updated for the user much like a subscription from GraphQL would do but I found out that subscriptions are tied to mutations and thus an update to the database from step functions will not trigger a subscription update on the frontend. To get around this I am using the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(getSubmissions, 5 * 1000)
})
```

Obviously this is a lot of overfetching and will probably incur unnecessary expense. I have looked for a better solution and come across DynamoDB streams but DynamoDB streams can't help me if they can't trigger the frontend to refresh the component. There has to be a better solution than what I have come up with.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This is my EXACT use case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, in AWS AppSync, to trigger a subscription publish you must trigger a GraphQL mutation.

> but I found out that subscriptions are tied to mutations and thus an
>   update to the database from step functions will not trigger a
>   subscription update on the frontend.

If you update your DynamoDB table directly via step functions or via DynamoDB streams, then AppSync has no way to know the data refreshed. 
Why don't you have your step function use an AppSync mutation instead of updating your table directly? That way you can link a subscription to the mutation and have your interested clients get pushed updates when the data is refreshed.

Comment: I did not think of this! I have sent this over to the guys doing the backend to see if we can pull this off. Thanks!

Comment: I did not even think I would find a SO for my exact use case. What a time to be a dev!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Cognito as your authentication for your AppSync application, you could set a lambda trigger on the dynamo table that generates a cognito token, and uses that make an authorized request to your mutation endpoint. NOTE: in your cognito userpool>app clients page, you will need to check the Enable username password auth for admin APIs for authentication (ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH) box to generate a client secret.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


const secrets = require('./secrets.js');
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
var config;





const adminAuth = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {

        const digest = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', config.SecretHash)
          .update(config.userName + config.ClientId)
          .digest('base64');

        var params = {
          AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
          ClientId: config.ClientId, /* required */
          UserPoolId: config.UserPoolId, /* required */
          AuthParameters: {
            'USERNAME': config.userName,
            'PASSWORD': config.password,
            "SECRET_HASH":digest
          },
        };
        cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminInitiateAuth(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err.stack);
              rej(err);
          }
          else {

              data.AuthenticationResult ? res(data.AuthenticationResult) : rej("Challenge requested, to verify, login to app using admin credentials");
          }
        }); 
});

const decode = auth => new Promise( res => {
    const decoded = jwt.decode(auth.AccessToken);
    auth.decoded = decoded
    res(auth);
});


//example gql query

 const testGql = auth =>  {
     const url = config.gqlEndpoint;

     const payload  = {
         query: `
           query ListMembers {
             listMembers {
               items{
                 firstName
                 lastName
               }
             }
           }
         ` 
     };


     console.log(payload);      
     const options = {
         headers: {
           "Authorization": auth.AccessToken
         },
     };

     console.log(options);
     return axios.post(url, payload, options).then(data =>  data.data)
     .catch(e => console.log(e.response.data));
 };






exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   await secrets() //some promise that returns your keys object (i use secrets manager)
   .then( keys => {
       #keys={ClientId:YOUR_COGNITO_CLIENT, 
       #      UserPoolId:YOUR_USERPOOL_ID,
       #      SecretHash:(obtained from cognito>userpool>app clients>app client secret),
       #      gqlEndpoint:YOUR_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
       #      userName:YOUR_COGNITO_USER,
       #      password:YOUR_COGNITO_USER_PASSWORD,
       #      }

       config = keys
       return adminAuth()
   })
   .then(auth => {
       return decode(auth)
   })
   .then(auth => {
       return testGql(auth)
   })
   .then( data => {
       console.log(data)
       callback(null, data)
   })
   .catch( e => {
       callback(e)
   })
};
```